# Skolem’s paradox

Tags: set-theory

https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509246

> ##### Anomaly #3: Skolem’s paradox.
>
> According to the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem, any infinite model of a countable family of axioms has a countable submodel.

> This can be applied to the standard axioms of set theory to infer the existence of a countable universe in which the ZFC axioms hold.

> In other words, if we restrict our attention to just those sets which belong to a certain countable set M, and ignore all other sets, we find that the standard axioms of set theory hold.

> (This is slightly subtle; perhaps the simplest accurate statement is that if inaccessible cardinals exist then there is a countable transitive set which models ZFC.)

> Skolem’s paradox is that since M satisfies the ZFC axioms and we can prove in ZFC that there exist uncountable sets, M must therefore contain uncountable sets, yet M itself is countable.

> **This puzzle is easily resolved (and indeed the resolution was already offered by Skolem): M “thinks” that some of its elements are uncountable because it does not contain a bijection between any of these sets and the natural numbers.**

> However, this does not prevent such bijections from existing outside M.

> The real import of Skolem’s paradox is the fact that M mimics the actual universe of sets so exactly that the latter becomes, for any mathematical purpose, completely superfluous.

> Moreover, it seems to place the actual universe so far out of our reach as to call our knowledge of its existence into question.

> “All commentators agree that the existence of such models shows that the ‘intended’ interpretation, or, as some prefer to speak, the ‘intuitive notion of a set’, is not ‘captured’ by the formal system.

> But if axioms cannot capture the ‘intuitive notion of a set’, what possibly could?” ([13], p. 465)

> In addition, the technique of forcing gives us a great deal of freedom to convert a given countable model M into other models M′, M′′, ... with various properties.

> **So apparently one is actually faced with a wide variety of countable models of the ZFC axioms, while only one (or a handful) of them is supposed to reflect the true properties of the real universe.**

> Yet we evidently have no way to determine which is which.

1. If M does not contain a bijection between a set and the natural numbers, and M is finite, does this simply mean that M does not contain a full copy of the natural numbers? It has gaps somewhere, like missing ordinal 3?
2. So the fundamental problem according to the author is that ZFC is supposed to describe “the real world”, but is shown to actually underdetermine any specific mathematical universe.

Comment: Huge literature available... [Skolem’s Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-skolem/): "Philosophical discussion of this paradox has tended to focus on *three main questions*. First, there's a purely mathematical question: why doesn't Skolem's Paradox introduce an outright contradiction into set theory? Second, there's a historical question. Skolem himself gave a pretty good explanation as to why Skolem's Paradox doesn't constitute a straightforward mathematical contradiction; why, then, did Skolem and his contemporaries continue to find the paradox so philosophically troubling?

Comment: Finally there's a purely philosophical question: what, if anything, does Skolem's Paradox tell us about our understanding of set theory and/or about the semantics of set-theoretic language?"

Comment: i) I don't think that is the right way to think about it. A model M may not correctly interpret the natural numbers- but still it's version of 3 will function like the "correct" ordinal 3. Whats happening here is that "x is countable" is of Sigma 1 Complexity in the Levy Heirarchy and is not absolute for Models of ZFC. Intuively, "bijections may be missing" - bijections are like rulers measuring sizes of things, M may be missing some rulers, and so cant accurately determine sizes.  Note: Countable here doesn't mean finite, it means of the same cardinality as the natural numbers.

Comment: ii) Yes, that's considered to be a fundamental problem- I've seen refered to as the Set Theoretic Multiverse Problem. Another Fundamental problem is related to independence Results, basic claims about Cardinality of Sets ( Continuum Hypothesis) is independent of the Axioms of ZFC, . Hugh Woodin is trying to resolve both of these fundamental issues with his Ultimate L Program.

Comment: I believe the downvotes to be unwarranted, and would urge my fellow forum users to comment their critiques so we can improve this question instead of leaving a downvote.